# Get latest winrar installer with cURL

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, curl

I'm tryng to **always** download the **latest** version of WinRAR in my **language** from the official site with **cURL** but can't figure out how the redirect link works.

The site https://www.win-rar.com/postdownload.html?&L=6&Version=32bit read the user agent to download the corresponding language version.

I try the following code whitout success:

```
curl -L --output winrar.exe -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0" "https://www.win-rar.com/postdownload.html?&L=6&Version=32bit"

curl --output winrar.exe -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0" "https://www.win-rar.com/postdownload.html?&L=6&Version=32bit"

curl --output winrar.exe -H "Host: www.win-rar.com" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0" -H "HTTPS: 1" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Referer: https://www.win-rar.com/postdownload.html?&L=6&Version=32bit" -H "Accept-Language: es-AR,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cookie: fe_typo_user=8820621858ced675661c51c70cf0015f; cookieDisclaimer=0" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "Sec-GPC: 1" -H "TE: Trailers" https://www.win-rar.com/postdownload.html?&L=6&Version=32bit
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: If your are using Windows, forget cURL, use Chocolatey instead.

Answer (score 0):

you may check the real world at "rarlab.com" NOT "win rar".
same content/manufacturer. there you get a full url that works using 'wget' or 'curl' otherwise you get a download depending of your running OS/Browser/client

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with **wget** using [darnir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952658/darnir) answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53288469

```
wget -r -l 1 --span-hosts --accept-regex=.*win-rar.com/fileadmin/winrar-versions/winrar/.*.exe -erobots=off -nH https://www.win-rar.com/postdownload.html?&L=6&Version=32bit
```